# How to install a large set of TTF fonts?

Tags: finder, font

On MacOS Monterey:

I have downloaded the [*JetBrains Mono* typeface](https://download.jetbrains.com/fonts/JetBrainsMono-2.304.zip?_gl=1*pc4fvi*_ga*MTc5NTgyNDY1NS4xNjg2MTM1MjIy*_ga_9J976DJZ68*MTY4NjEzNTIyMS4xLjEuMTY4NjEzNTQyMS42MC4wLjA.&_ga=2.169561698.276122232.1686135222-1795824655.1686135222). This is a zip-file containing 69 TTF-files. How can I add them to MacOS? The JetBrains website shows in their installation instructions only how to install them for their IDE, which I don't plan to use.

I found an [Apple Support Page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201749), which explains how to install a single font file: Use Finder to open the font directory and then do a double click on the font file.

Do I have to repeat this 69 times for all files, or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several way you can do it.

Select all in Finder. Right click > Open with > FontBook
[can't have any folders selected this way, just fonts.]

If Font Book is already open…
Drag & drop the entire folder onto Font Book.
*or*
Use the Open menu in Font Book & select the entire folder in the file picker.

These last two methods will ignore folders, text files etc & just import the useable fonts.

Answer (score 3):

- Open Font Book
- Drag&drop all font files into it

or

- Select all fonts in Finder
- Right-click on selection and select “Open“

Answer (score 1):

You can also just drag the fonts into `/Library/Fonts` or `~/Library/Fonts` (the user library) in the Finder, bypassing FontBook altogether.

They can be in a subfolder, to maintain organization, if you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a way to install the fonts programmatically (without having to reach for the mouse) this is the method I use:

https://github.com/luckman212/font-installer

The script checks the locally-installed font version, compares it with the latest available from GitHub, and downloads and installs the fonts if necessary.

@benwiggy: Not sure what to make of your comment. Homebrew's pretty common, and the script is provided as an example—the dependencies could be removed if necessary.

Comment: "Requires Homebrew and installs some stuff."

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using the application `Font Book`:

1. Open Font Book
2. Click on the left side pane on "All Fonts"
3. Use the menu "File/AddFonts"
4. Navigate to the directory having the fonts
5. Select all fonts (using Apple-A)

The crucial point is here item 2. If **All Fonts** is not selected, the *Add Fonts* menu item might be greyed out (at least this was the case for me).